# What happens to my events when I change my time zone on Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, time-zone

I am currently living in the Pacific US time zone, but I may be doing a summer internship in Eastern time zone, which is 3 hours ahead. What will happen to the existing events when I change my time zone on Google Calendar? Will they remain at the same absolute time or will they shift 3 hours forward in absolute time so that they remain at the same clock time in my new time zone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They will shift to match the time zone when you created the event. For example an event at 15:00 in pacific time will remain at 15:00 in pacific time, but in your new time zone will be shown at 18:00 in eastern time zone.